# VueJS :href interprets external links as internal links

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using VueJS and Vuetify. When passing a link to an anchor using `:href` it interprets it as an external link. For example:
`www.example.com` brings me to `localhost/www.example.com` but `https://www.example.com` would bring me to `www.example.com`.

Here is my code :

```html
<a :href="link.link" target="_blank">
    {{ link.text }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your URLs are full and not relative.

If they are missing the scheme (`https://` for example), they will be interpreted as relative link.

You don't show the code where you prepare the `links` array, so in general you can iterate them to fix this, or if you are building the array in the code already, you would probably want to add this there.

```js
let linksArr = //...
for (const linkObj of linksArr) {
 linkObj.link = linkObj.link.startsWith('http://') || linkObj.link.startsWith('https://') ?
    linkObj.link : `https://${linkObj.link}`;
}

// or

linksArr = linksArr.map((linkObj) => {
  return {
    ...linkObj,
    link: linkObj.link.startsWith('http://') || linkObj.link.startsWith('https://') ?
      linkObj.link : `https://${linkObj.link}`
  };
});
```